# Cocos 3d crashes, it says it can't load a texture

Tags: ios, 3d, cocos3d

I have to download a .pod file and a folder with the texture images.
Afterwards I have to load the pod file, and I should see a nice 3D image.

```
//podNr is the id of the pod.
NSString *url2 = @"http://(MY URL FOR POD FILE);
NSString *urlIm2 = @"http:(MY URL FOR TEXTURE FOLDER);

NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:url2];
NSURL *UrlIm = [NSURL URLWithString:urlIm2];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *podFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PODFILE%d.pod",podNr];


NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:podFile];

NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/images"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder

NSMutableData *urlData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:Url];

NSMutableData *urlImageData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:UrlIm];

NSString *folder = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:UrlIm encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"FOLDER CONTENT:%@",folder);
if (folder != nil) {
    [self getImages:folder andpodNr:podNr];
}


NSLog(@"urlIMAGE:%d",[urlImageData length]);


[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"sucsesfully written to file:%d",[urlData length]);


[self addContentFromPODFile: filePath];
```

Here is the code for the addImages function:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getImages:(NSString *)html andpodNr:(int)podNr
{
NSMutableArray *outPut = [NSMutableArray alloc];
NSString *S = html;
NSString *rest;

while(TRUE)
{
    if ([S rangeOfString:@".jpg\""].location == NSNotFound) {
        return outPut;
    }
    else {
        //existe .jpg!

        int jpgPos = 0;

        int rangeOfCom = 0;
        NSString *auxS = S;

        while (TRUE) {
            jpgPos = [auxS rangeOfString:@".jpg\""].location;
            rangeOfCom = [auxS rangeOfString:@"\""].location;
            if (rangeOfCom == NSNotFound) {
                return outPut;
            }
            if (rangeOfCom > jpgPos) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                auxS = [auxS substringFromIndex:rangeOfCom+1];
            }
        }
        NSString *result = [auxS substringToIndex:rangeOfCom];
        rest = [auxS substringFromIndex:rangeOfCom+1];
        NSLog(@"RESULT:%@",result);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *newResult = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/images/%@",newResult];

        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:newPath];

        NSString *urlIm2 = @"http://(MY URL FOR IMAGES);
        NSLog(@"URL:%@",urlIm2);
        NSURL *urlA = [NSURL URLWithString:urlIm2];
        NSMutableData *imgData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlA];
        [imgData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        NSLog(@"Written %d to %@",[[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] length],filePath);
    }
    S = rest;
}

return outPut;
```

Here is the output:

```
2012-11-29 15:12:07.324 homy2[1181:207] FOLDER CONTENT:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-      //W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /models/1685740/m/images</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /models/1685740/m/images</h1>
<ul><li><a href="/models/1685740/m/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href="wood%202.jpg"> wood 2.jpg</a></li>
</ul>
</body></html>
2012-11-29 15:12:07.326 homy2[1181:207] RESULT:wood%202.jpg
2012-11-29 15:12:07.327 homy2[1181:207] URL:http://(MY URL)models/1685740/m/images/wood%202.jpg
2012-11-29 15:12:07.911 homy2[1181:207] Written 50443 to /Users/demianschkolnikmuller/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/685E679A-E6D9-4834-952E-9158BB37C2B9/Documents/images/wood 2.jpg
2012-11-29 15:12:07.911 homy2[1181:207] urlIMAGE:315
2012-11-29 15:12:07.913 homy2[1181:207] successfully written to file:21600
2012-11-29 15:12:07.944 homy2[1181:207] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
2012-11-29 15:12:07.945 homy2[1181:207] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:wood 2.jpg in CCTextureCache
2012-11-29 15:12:07.946 homy2[1181:207] [***ERROR***] CC3Texture wood%202.jpg-1 could not load texture from file wood 2.jpg
```

So there are several things.. as you can see, it says
    successfully written to file:21600
so it IS downloading and writing things... 
The simulator simply crashes.
any ideas? please ask for additional info if you need it.
Thanks a lot in advance and I am sorry for the long post.

Comment: It seems to be going wrong with a UIImage object being nil.  Does that happen in `addContentFromPODFile`?

Comment: @Phillip yes, it happens there.. weird thing is thou, if the size of the texture is too big, for example 4096 x 4096, then it says    warning: texture size too big, supported size is 2048 x 2048 . If you look for this in the code, the warning comes AFTER the 'UIIMage is nil' thing. So if it is big, its not nil, but I only made the texture smaller...

Comment: What's the code to create the UIImage object?  ...sounds like that's failing.

Comment: I have no idea where the UIImage is created.. cocos3d does that for me.. I just download all the necessary files and then call addContentFromPODFile.

Comment: UPDATE: I traced the creation of the UIImage back to CC3TextureCache, where the 'addImage' method is invoked. I made a new function, addImage2, identical to the first one, except I replaced
    NSString *fullpath = [CCFileUtils fullPathFromRelativePath: path ];  with simply NSString *fullpath = path, because the path I give now is absolute, it is something like this: PATH:/Users/demianschkolnikmuller/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/685E679A-E6D9-4834-952E-9158BB37C2B9/Documents/images/wood%202.jpg
Now the console shows no errors.. but the app crashes anyway =/

Comment: UPDATE 2: here:
`UIImage *jpg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
   UIImage *png = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(jpg)];
   tex = [ [CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage: png ];`

in the method `initWithImage` the app fails, it says indeed : `CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil`

Any ideas?? =(

Comment: UPDATE 3:
After running with a lot of breakpoints, I came to this line:
   `UIImage *jpg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];`
Here, the fullpath exists, and is:
`/Users/demianschkolnikmuller/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/685E679A-E6D9-4834-952E-9158BB37C2B9/Documents/images/1857088-MESA%20TOLEDO45%2045X45X45-negra.JPG`
but jpg remains null. I went directly with the finder and the file actually exists and I can look at it without trouble.

Comment: `initWithContentsOfFile:` says it will also return nil if it can't create an image from the file's data.  Can you open that saved file in something like Preview or Gimp to test whether it's a good image?

Comment: yes, I open it with preview and its good. Changed it to test that and the same happens.